# Vim-LaTeXsuite shows me my .bbl file for errors in the .tex file

Tags: errors, vim

I'm writing my doctoral dissertation in LaTeX with Vim-LaTeXsuite, and I find that Vim-LaTeXsuite is often determining the location of errors incorrectly, particularly when the error is a `\ref{}` to an nonexistent `\label{}`. Vim-LaTeXsuite will get the line number correct, but it will assume that the error is in the .bbl file. It will load the .bbl file in the main buffer, and I'll have to use `:e` to load the .tex file again before I can fix the error.

Is there any way to fix this? I'm already using `-file-line-error`, but it doesn't seem to change the format of the `Citation missing` error messages.

(I have not been able to create a minimal example of this.)

Comment: We will close the question for know. We can open it if you would add some more details such as a minimal example.